# How to alter title bar height for access form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, properties, datasheet

Is there a way of altering the title bar height for a form (actually a subform) when it is displayed in datasheet mode?

My field titles are often longer than the data and there is not very much I can do about this. It's not a problem when the form is in 'Single Form' view, but there will be lots of times when the datasheet view is helpful, because it's a good summary of info.

I had thought that forcing a new line in the field title might work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Access does not allow for this to be done.  The standard way most Access developers circumnavigate this issue is to use labels.  Set your DatasheetCaptions to blanks ("") and use labels as your column headers.  This way you can multi-line them or format them however you want.