# Is there a way to make a field label in forms datasheet mode to be multi-line?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I need a reasonably long label name but don't want to make the datasheet column unnecessarily large since the corresponding data is not large.  Is there a way to get Access to break the label into multiple lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of the question here: [How to alter title bar height for access form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831418/how-to-alter-title-bar-height-for-access-form) and here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-can-you-change-an-access-datasheet-column-header-height-or-wra.3309187/, No, Access doesn't have this capability.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  That answers my question and prompted me to look at whether continuous forms might be a better implementation.

Comment: With a little work you can make a continuous form look fairly close to a datasheet but have a lot more functionality available.